# python- Insert query to store regex expression in mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, regex, cherrypy

**Insert query for string having \" character in it in mysql db**-

How to write **insert query for string such as**:

This is the string i want to insert into my table,

```
reg="item-cell\"(.*?)</span></div>"

cur = db.cursor()
query='INSERT into table_name(col_name) values("%s")'%(reg)
cur.execute(query)
cur.close()
```

Below is the **error**:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'(.*?)</span></div>")\' at line 1')
```

I know its something related to escape character, but don't know how to make that work.

**EDIT:** This string reg is variable i.e. I am getting this string from some API and I want to insert it into my database. So inserting escape characters in between the string literal will not suffice my case. I want something that can generalize single quote, double quote or one double quote(eg. **reg**) all these cases.

I hope I made my point clear.

**EDIT:**  This is how i am getting the value of reg(froma json file)

```
import urllib, json
import MySQLdb
url = "some_url"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
for item in data["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"]:
    prop=str(item)
    reg=str(data["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"][prop]["regex"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the part where you convert the json object to string. To properly do this without altering the string you need to use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

```
for item in data["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"]:
    prop = json.dumps(item)
    reg = json.dumps(data["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"][prop]["regex"])
```

Comment: This is good when i have just one string but what if i have thousands of such strings. Surely, we are not going to check for every string. Is there any way that can generalise this?

Comment: @ujjawlsaini I edited the answer to use raw strings, have u tried that yet?

Comment: Yeah, this works fine.
But the way you have written the string "item-cell\"(.*?)</span></div>" as r"item-cell\"(.*?)</span></div>", How to write same for variable holding the string. Like say "mystr" is what i am getting from some API, now how to write for this 
reg= r"mystr". I know this is not correct, Hope you understand what i am asking.

Comment: It failed for this - "item-cell\"(.*?)</span></div>"
resulting as" item-cell"(.*?)</span></div>"

Comment: @ujjawlsaini can you post the code that gets the string? after testing for a while, it turns out that if you get a string as input from user using 'raw_input()' python 2.x or 'input()' python 3.x it is already a raw string, the same applies if its read from a file.

Comment: @ujjawlsaini updated the answer with the new solution, I hope it works this time :)

Comment: you saved my life dude! Yes you caught the problem right. Just a small change, instead of doing " reg.encode('string-escape') " , I did reg = reg[1:-1], because it was returning " "some_value" " so i removed first and last comma's. It worked for me.

Comment: @ujjawlsaini Am glad it worked, don't forget to mark the answer, good luck!